# local.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, laravel, server, ubuntu-16.04

I've uploaded my laravel 5.6 project on Ubuntu 16.04.4.
When i upload my working project(API's tested on postman) on it, it returns a blank response and on the url it states "This page isn’t working" "HTTP ERROR 500".

From what I've learnt is that the php version of my project and is different from the one on the server.

My project is built on php 7.1.9 and the server php version is 7.1.18

Any form of help or information will be useful.
Thank you in advance

**Log:**

```
local.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThr$
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/var/www/narcod...')
#1 [internal function]: Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\\\\Compone...')
#2 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCompiler.php(39): spl_autoload_call('Symfony\\\\Compone...')
#3 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(284): Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCompiler->compile()
#4 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(261): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->compileRoute()
#5 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->matches(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), t$
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), 'api/user')
#7 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php(175): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), 'api/user')
#8 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(657): Illuminate\\Support\\Arr::first(Array, Object(Closure), NULL)
#9 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php(198): Illuminate\\Support\\Collection->first(Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php(164): Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection->matchAgainstRoutes(Object(Illumin$
#11 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(619): Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(608): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(597): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(O$
#16 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Obj$
#18 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illumina$
#19 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\$
#20 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Il$
#21 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illumina$
#22 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\$
#23 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Il$
#24 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illumina$
#25 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\$
#26 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Ill$
#27 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illumina$
#28 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(51): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Ro$
#29 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Obj$
#30 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illumina$
#31 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illumina$
#32 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#33 /var/www/narcodes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Il$
#34 /var/www/narcodes/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Without your code / error logs / more information, we can't really help.

Comment: I'm fairly sure your server isn't running 7.1.18.  This is usually the error I see from PHP 5.6 or below when using null coalescing operators.

Comment: @Devon its 7.1.18 , I've used multiple php versions to check if they work like 5.6, 7.2 but they did'nt work

Comment: Simple check, just output [`phpversion`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) and see what you get.

Comment: if more information is required please let me know, I'm new to this so i dont know what all should i provide so that you can help me

Comment: Add `<?php phpinfo();` to info.php in the public directory, browse to /info.php.  If it says PHP 7.1, then it means the problem is in your code somewhere, but the stack trace doesn't do a good job of saying where.

Comment: i did as you asked @Devon 
when i use "php -v" on cli it says php 7.1.18 but with phpinfo() it says 7.0.30 on the top
any idea how to bring them both to the same version?

Comment: Without knowing how you have your server configured, no.  It's a bit broad for SO to discuss web server configuration.  If the project is important to you, hire a real system administration that can setup, secure, and maintain the server for you.

Comment: It's working now , i changed laravel framework from 5.6.* to 5.5.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is because your php server version, can be different from what you see when doing php -v.

The right way to check this is to do a php info on your server side, not on CLI.

If you need to enable php 7.2 on apache this is the command on ubuntu

first disable old php version

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
```

enable new version

```
sudo a2enmod php7.2
```